# Query with mysql_fetch_assoc and echo doesn't return results

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my PHP file.
First of all, here's my code:

```
<?php

$users = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT u.*, ui.*, SUM(`Beach Ball` + `Sun Blocker`) AS items FROM user AS u INNER JOIN user_item AS ui ON u.user_id = ui.user_id WHERE u.user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' GROUP BY u.user_id"));

echo "<table><tr><td>User</td><td>Day of Trip</td><td>Items</td></tr>";

while($list=mysql_fetch_array($users)){

    echo "<tr><td>" .$list['user']. "</td><td>" .$list['trip']. "</td>"
    echo "<td>".$list['item']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And my DB is something like:

User: Jack / Suzy / Steve

Trip: Sunday / Sunday / Monday

Items: Jack (Beach Ball & Sun Blocker = 1) / Suzy (Sun Blocker = 1 | Beach Ball = 0) / Steve (Beach Ball = 2 / Sun Blocker = 1)

---

About version:

PHP 5.3.27 / MySQL 5.5.32

(Also, that's a little example about my code, it's all in Dutch).

If anyone could help me on this, I'll be eternally grateful.

PS: If I try a simple query, like:

```
$users = mysql_query("select * from users")
```

It will list only User and Trip (because information about items is in another table, that lists down all item (more than 35)...

~x~

Update 1: (PHP & SQL version updated)
This code works on a free hosting plan (like co.gp or bytehost) but it isn't working on a paid host.

Comment: Don't use `mysql` anymore: See the red box: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, use PDO or `mysqli`

Comment: You are using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` completely wrong, please read the documentation.

Comment: You are fetching the fetched results: `mysql_fetch_array( mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ) )` which does not make sense.

Comment: @1ntello
Is it normal to MySQLi converter result on this kind of line?
    $users = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],

For me, it's kinda weird, but if it's normal, then I'll try to MySQLi

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario
I forgot to say that my code worked on a free hosting and it isn't working on my paid host... Sorry :|

Comment: @KarynYukizawa read the documentation right here for the correct use of mysqli_fetch_assoc() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

You have already fetched your result in line 1. Try this

```
<?php

$users = mysql_query("SELECT u.*, ui.*, SUM(`Beach Ball` + `Sun Blocker`) AS items FROM user AS u INNER JOIN user_item AS ui ON u.user_id = ui.user_id WHERE u.user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' GROUP BY u.user_id") or die('error in query execution'); //fire your query

echo "<table><tr><td>User</td><td>Day of Trip</td><td>Items</td></tr>";

while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){ //use mysql_fetch_assoc here

    echo "<tr><td>" .$list['user']. "</td><td>" .$list['trip']. "</td>"
    echo "<td>".$list['item']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Sidenote: `MySQL_*` is deprecated use `PDO` or `MySQLi_*` instead.

Comment: Tried to use your code and... Nothing =\

I'll try to use MySQLi